# Redirect function output to printf state ment seems not working in bash

Tags: linux, bash, function, printf

Have created simple bash script as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a message_list=("ok" "error" "cancel")

display_output_message()
{
    message_index=$1
    message_type=$2

    if [ $message_index -gt 2 ]
    then
        printf "Invalid Message index\n"
        exit 0
    fi

    if [ $message_type -eq 1 ]
    then
        printf "%s\n" $message_index
    else
        printf "%s\n" "${message_list[$message_index]}"
    fi
}

printf "message :: %s %s\n" "display_output_message $1 $2" "received"
```

From above scripts i want to call `display_output_message()` function from `printf` and print the output of that function in `printf` statement from which it called. I have no idea how to redirect function out put to `printf`. So far what i have tried is shown above script and when i run script then is show me output as follows

```
$ ./script.bash 1 2
message :: display_output_message 1 2 received
```

So `printf` just print the name of function which i want to call and argument list but i want output as follows

```
$ ./script.bash 1 2
message :: ok received
```

I missed something minor or might be not knowlegde of how redirect output to `printf` .

Have any one idea how can i solve it.?

Comment: Two tips: you probably want to use `return`, not `exit`, in the function, and usually a return value of 0 indicates success; a non-zero value indicates a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to actually *call* that function. Right now you're just passing a piece of text.

Try this:

```
printf "message :: %s %s\n" "$(display_output_message $1 $2)" "received"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but output comes `message :: received ` which not valid it miss `ok`. are you getting me?. Have run on your desk?